# Recursively generate tuple of all distinct types referenced by a struct

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, metaprogramming

I'm specifying a graph of types at compile time with `using`s and `std::tuple`s like this:

```
#include<tuple>

struct C;

struct A
{
    using ReferencedTypes = std::tuple<>;
};

struct B
{
    using ReferencedTypes = std::tuple<C>;
};

struct C
{
    using ReferencedTypes = std::tuple<B, A>;
};

struct D
{
    using ReferencedTypes = std::tuple<A, B, C>;
};

struct E
{
    using ReferencedTypes = std::tuple<C, B>;
};
```

What I would like is a way to recursively get a tuple of all the distinct types referenced by any one of these types (Including the top-level type). The order of the elements of the tuple doesn't matter. Something like:

```
// DistinctTypes is a std::tuple<E, C, B, A>;
using DistinctTypes = all_types_referenced_in_graph<E>::value;
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Fixing existing code is easier than writing from scratch.

Comment: Yes, but my metaprogramming knowledge is so basic I really don't think anything I wrote is helpful

Comment: I didn't succeed to handle loop (C->B->C) yet [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/333052927d790a1b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My template metaprogramming skills are rusty, but I have something working that will correctly ignore the cycles.

For example, I'm sure a better answer will not force the use of `std::tuple_cat` and SFINAE.

For the sake of readability, I used `requires` instead of SFINAE dark arts.

First, let's write a metafunction that will search linearly in a tuple to find if an element is there. If it's there, return true. Otherwise, return false:

```
// Base case
template<typename Elem, typename Tuple>
struct tuple_contains : std::false_type {};

// Iteration. We extend the type until result. Looks like recursion.
// We drop the first element of the tuple for the next iteration, until none.
template<typename T, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct tuple_contains<T, std::tuple<First, Rest...>> : tuple_contains<T, std::tuple<Rest...>> {};

// Success! T is the same as the first element of the tuple!
template<typename T, typename... Rest>
struct tuple_contains<T, std::tuple<T, Rest...>> : std::true_type {};
```

Using that, we can make a class that will recursively go into tuples, and append a type into a list only if that element is not in the list:

```
// We will only use specializations
template<typename TupIn, typename TupOut = std::tuple<>>
struct recursive_append_unique;

// End case. No more types to process.
template<typename... TsOut>
struct recursive_append_unique<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<TsOut...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<TsOut...>;
};

// Here we receive std::tuple<T, TsIn...> where T is already in TsOut.
// In that case, we skip it since it's already processed
template<typename T, typename... TsIn, typename... TsOut>
requires (tuple_contains<T, std::tuple<TsOut...>>::value)
struct recursive_append_unique<std::tuple<T, TsIn...>, std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = recursive_append_unique<std::tuple<TsIn...>, std::tuple<TsOut...>>::type;
};

// Here we have a T that is not in TsOut.
// Here's the core of the algorithm: We add T into TsOut,
// But we also add all types on T::ReferencedTypes into TsIn.
// The next iteration will take care of the first type we added into TsIn.
template<typename T, typename... TsIn, typename... TsOut>
struct recursive_append_unique<std::tuple<T, TsIn...>, std::tuple<TsOut...>> {
    using type = recursive_append_unique<decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<typename T::ReferencedTypes>(), std::declval<std::tuple<TsIn...>>())), std::tuple<TsOut..., T>>::type;
};
```

Here's a usage of it with your code:

```
int main() {
    static_assert(std::same_as<recursive_append_unique<std::tuple<E>>::type, std::tuple<E, C, B, A>>);
}
```

I'm sure this can be done way simpler, but it's been quite a while since I've done anything with template metaprograms.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Mvn7Yjj63)

The requires clause can be replaced by a dummy third template parameter defaulted to `void`, combined with `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: Use [C++17 fold-expressions](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to replace `tuple_contains`: `template <class T, class... Us> concept matches_any = (std::same_as<T, Us> || ...);` As an aside, the requires-clause if fulfilled makes the specialization more specialized, thus no need for the negated one.

Comment: Here's another monstrocity I came up with: https://godbolt.org/z/KrWPhPhdr

Comment: Simplified my `tuple_cat_uniq`: https://godbolt.org/z/EdWbezveK